# Changing picture on python guizero grid when clicked

Tags: python, image, user-interface, grid, guizero

I have been having a terrible problem and would really, really appreciate it that somebody could help me...

Can this be fixed?

So basically, on guizero python I want a button to update a picture when clicked.
Here on my battleship game, I have a grid with each picture being a water tile. When clicked on the water tile I want it to be updated so that the it displays a hit water tile.

I have tried to make it so:

```
def hit():
    button_11.image = "images/shipbroken.GIF"

button_11 = PushButton(window, image="images/watergrid.GIF",  grid=[1, 1], height = 100, width = 100) 

button_11.whenclicked = hit
```

This should go to the subroutine "hit" when clicked and update button_11's image to a destroyed tile. I dont know why this is not working and I feel the solution is obvious but out of reach *facepalm*

Comment: I have got all of my other parts needed to run guizero such as importing and app display as well.

Comment: Oh yes and it does not give and error it just simply does not work. A logical error probably? not syntax...

Comment: if you have new information the edit question instead of writing in comment.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see if this function is executed. And run code in console/terminal to see if this gives error . I would expect that function has to get soem parameters - like `event` or `x,y` or `mouse_button`

Comment: are you sure it has to be `whenclicked`? mabye it has to be something different - ie. `on_press` or `command`. Source code for [PushButton](https://github.com/lawsie/guizero/blob/master/guizero/PushButton.py) shows that it can get `PushButton(..., command=function)` and it has also `.update_command(function)`- and I think you should use `PushButton(..., command=hit)` or `button_11.update_command(hit)`

Comment: when I check [documentation](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/start/) then I also see `PushButton(app, text="Press me", command=change_message)` and description `The PushButton widget includes a "command" parameter which is set to the name of a function - "change_message". The "change_message" function is called each time the button is clicked.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on [documentation](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/start/) and
source code [PushButton](https://github.com/lawsie/guizero/blob/master/guizero/PushButton.py) you should use `command=hit`

```
button_11 = PushButton(window, 
                       image="images/watergrid.GIF",  
                       grid=[1, 1], 
                       height=100, 
                       width=100, 
                       command=hit)
```

Eventually

```
button_11.update_command(hit)
```